# Off Canvas - Left Navbar animation very jumpy/laggy on close

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create an Offcanvas Left nav bar that can be brought into view on button click.

Currently it opens fine but when it closes the top navigation of the page is very jumpy and closes instantly without an animation.

The left bar also overlaps the footer and the footer doesn't move the way it should like the top nav bar.

[Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/tgJ0hQ3ZlG)

Comment: Adding -webkit-transition: all 1s ease; at your wrapper class should fix the sliding. I´ll try to come up with a fix for the footer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease; to the footer and wrapper class, because everything has to be animated.

I set overflow hidden on html, body selector, this is a fix for the jumpy footer.

The only thing left to do now is adding two lines in your javascript:
$(".footer").css('-webkit-transform', 'translate(20%, 0)');

and

(".footer").css('-webkit-transform', 'translate(0, 0)');

I'm no expert so feel free to correct me, but i think it works the way you want it to.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var menu = "close";

  $(".menuToggle").click(function() {
    if (menu == "close") {
      $(".leftNavbar").css("-webkit-transform", "translate(0, 0)");
      $(".wrapper").css('-webkit-transform', 'translate(20%, 0)');
      $(".footer").css('-webkit-transform', 'translate(20%, 0)');
      menu = "open";
    } else {
      $(".leftNavbar").css("-webkit-transform", "translate(-100%, 0)");
      $(".wrapper").css('-webkit-transform', 'translate(0, 0)');
      $(".footer").css('-webkit-transform', 'translate(0, 0)');
      menu = "close";
    }

  });
});
```

```css
/* CSS used here will be applied after bootstrap.css */

.leftNavbar {
  position: fixed;
  width: 20%;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: green;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-100%, 0);
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
}
.menuToggle .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  background-color: black;
}
.menuToggle .navbar-toggle {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-top: -10px;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: auto !important;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto -40px;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
}
footer,
.push {
  min-height: 40px;
  height: auto;
}
.footer {
  color: white;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="leftNavbar">
  <h2>Sidebar menu</h2>
  <nav>
    <a href="#">Home</a>
    <a href="#">About</a>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
    <a href="#">Prices</a>
  </nav>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" role="navigation">

    <div class="container">

      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>

        <a class="navbar-brand">
          <img id="logo" src="Logos/LetterHillustrator.png">
        </a>

      </div>


      <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="Services.html">Services</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="Prices.html">Our Prices</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="AboutUs.html">About Us</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="Contact.php">Contact Us</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <!--------SIDE NAVBAR-------->

  <!--<div class="leftNavbar">
                <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                  <li class="active"><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span> Home</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span> Option 1</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" class="active2"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span> Option 2 (active)</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span> Option 3</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span> Option 4</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span> Option 5</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>-->

  <!-----SIDEBAR------->



  <div class="menuToggle">
    <button class="navbar-toggle">
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
  </div>



  <div class="push"></div>

</div>

<footer class="footer navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container">
    <h6 style="width:50%; text-align:center;">34 The Broadway, Greenford UB6 9PT, tel: 020 8575 0880, Email: info@GoodHome.co.uk</h6>
  </div>
</footer>
```